# Where UserDefaults save a custom suite

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

Where iOS saves on disk a custom UserDefaults suites?

```
let testSuite = UserDefaults(suiteName: "testSuite")
    testSuite?.set("My test value for defaults",
                    forKey: "sameKey")
```

Answer (score 2):

They are saved in the same location as the standard UserDefaults.

`Library/Preferences/SuiteName.plist`